# Will resetting my KitKat android force me to upgrade to Lollipop?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, rooting, factory-reset

I have a galaxy s4 running a rooted kitkat system. If I upgrade to lollipop I cannot root phone (which I need!) Will doing a factory reset force me to upgrade or will I retain my kitkat system?

Answer (score 1):

A factory reset of your phone will not cause an upgrade of the operating system. You will still have the whatever OS you started with.